# How to use AND and OR function in excel to reach a decision

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

See the following image:

[image]

So, in this picture there are only 0s and 1s, and that is how it is setup.

Now, in the yellow box, where there is 1, I have put the condition as seen in the second yellow box. But, that is not the condition I want.

I want to check whether one or more cells for "A" are 1 or not. With that I also need to check whether one or more cells for "B" are 1 or not. If at least one cell in both "A" and "B" are 1, then write 1 otherwise write 0.

I hope that make sense. Thanks

Comment: So write the function with "or()": IF(OR(B3=1,C3=1),1,0), the two result values don't need to be in quotes as True or 1 is valid.

Comment: @SolarMike Let me try it

Comment: it does exactly what you have asked for as in: "If at least one cell in both "A" and "B" are 1, then write 1 otherwise write 0"

Comment: I wrote the expression with OR() in it for you

Comment: B3 or B4 or B5 or B6 AND C3 or C4 or C5 or C6. Does it solve that? Meaning from B3-B6 at least one of them needs to be 1 and from C3-C6 atleast one of them needs to be 1. Then, the condition is true (1) otherwise false(0).

Comment: enter the function in c3 and drag it down... the function will pick up the b4 c4 etc, but will only work on the same row.

Comment: I need that function for one cell.

Comment: the way you worded your question leads to misunderstandings. Do you want "0" if all 8 values in `B3:C6` are 0 and "1" if any of the 8 values is 1?

Comment: How about: IF(AND(SUM(C3:C6)>=1,SUM(D3:D6)>=1),1,0)

Comment: @Slai I am sorry. I know it is confusing to explain it. You are close but I need A and B separate. So, if any of the 4 values in row A is 1 AND if any of the 4 values in row B is 1, then the result is 1. But, if none of the values in row A are 1, even if one or more are 1 for B, then that results in false.

Comment: @Solar Mike. I want to avoid the sum function. Sorry. See if you understand my reply to Slai.

Comment: your reply to Slai does not preclude the sum function...

Comment: So how about: IF(AND(C5:C10>=1,D5:D10>=1),1,0), sorry worked now doesn't

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: So =IF(AND(OR(C3=1, C4=1, C5=1, C6=1),OR(D3=1, D4=1, D5=1, D6=1)),1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(A3:A6)>0,SUM(B3:B6)>0),1,0)
```

You might want to name your ranges AList and BList. Then you could use:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(AList) >0,SUM(BList)>0),1,0)
```

Which makes it clearer what you're doing.

Comment: Why not avoid the sum function? It is okay because this is in excel, but in theory that is incorrect.

Comment: or just `=SIGN(SUM(G2:G5)*SUM(H2:H5))`

Comment: Would this serve your needs better?
=IF(AND(OR(A5,A6,A7,A8),OR(B5,B6,B7,B8)),1,0)

Comment: I meant to say:
=IF(AND(OR(A3,A4,A5,A6),OR(B3,B4,B5,B6)),1,0)

Comment: Nice, it can be even shorter `=OR(B3:B6)*OR(C3:C6)`

Answer (score 0):

```
= IF( AND( OR(B3=1,B4=1,B5=1,B6=1), OR(C3=1,C4=1,C5=1,C6=1) ), "1", "0" )
```

is a bit long and not flexible if the range changes, but you can change it to array formula like this:

```
= IF( AND( OR(B3:B6 = 1), OR(C3:C6 = 1) ), "1", "0" )
```

and enter it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter